# General Solution of the Diff Equation y''=-ky

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

That equation comes up quite a lot in physics. It's general solution is a well-known result. If we take a look at Feynman's *FLP*, in the chapter of the harmonic oscillator, he gives the general solution to this D.E in therms of a linear combination of sines and cosines. Let $y=y(t)$:
\begin{equation}
y=Acos(\omega_0t)+Bsin(\omega_0t)
\end{equation}

As brilliant as his approach is, is not a mathematical one. Since that's a linear equation with constant coefficients, I did the standard method, evaluated the roots of its characteristic polynomial, and used a general formula, getting:
\begin{equation}
y=C_1e^{\sqrt{k}t}+C_2e^{-\sqrt{k}x}
\end{equation}

Of course, I'm aware of the relationship between the complex numbers and the oscilators, so how sines and cosines could arrive from this solution is not totally obscure to me. But I do not know how one can mathematically get there.

Answer (score 2):

If $k>0$ then you don't get sinusoids (at least not with real frequencies). You get exponentials.

When $k<0$ the second approach yields complex exponentials $e^{i\sqrt{|k|}x}$ and $e^{-i\sqrt{|k|}x}$. These combine to sinusoids with suitable coefficients; in particular $\frac{1}{2} e^{i\sqrt{|k|}x} + \frac{1}{2} e^{-i\sqrt{|k|} x}=\cos(\sqrt{|k|}x)$ and $\frac{1}{2i} e^{i\sqrt{|k|}x} - \frac{1}{2i} e^{-i\sqrt{|k|} x}=\sin(\sqrt{|k|}x)$.

Comment: Gah... I looked over the minus sign, the actual equation is y''=-ky, therefore your development. Thanks a lot, though.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging the original equation:
$y''+ky=0$.

Subbing the guessed ansatz $y=e^{\lambda t}$, we get
$$
\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+ke^{\lambda t}=0
$$
Factoring-out the exponential, we have
$$
\left(\lambda^2+k\right)e^{\lambda t}=0
$$
So its sufficient for the characteristic polynomial to be zero:
$$
\lambda^2+k=0
$$
With complex solutions equal to
$$
\lambda = \pm i\sqrt{k}
$$
So we take a linear combination of two solutions with those values of for $\lambda$:
$$
y(t) = Ae^{i\sqrt{k}t}+Be^{-i\sqrt{k}t},
$$
which is a general solution for arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$ we usually select to meet initial/boundary conditions. On the other hand, we know the following facts about sine and cosine:
$$
\cos(\sqrt{k}t) = \frac{e^{i\sqrt{k}t}+e^{-i\sqrt{k}t}}{2}
$$
$$
\sin(\sqrt{k}t) = \frac{e^{i\sqrt{k}t}-e^{-i\sqrt{k}t}}{2i}
$$
So we can just as easily write:
$$
y(t) = C_1\cos(\sqrt{k}t)+C_2\sin(\sqrt{k}t),
$$
and this is identical to the above for the right values of $C_1$ and $C_2$. To see this, equate the two and sub what we know
$$
C_1\cos(\sqrt{k}t)+C_2\sin(\sqrt{k}t) = Ae^{i\sqrt{k}t}+Be^{-i\sqrt{k}t}
$$
$$
C_1\left(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{k}t}+e^{-i\sqrt{k}t}}{2}\right)+C_2\left(\frac{e^{i\sqrt{k}t}-e^{-i\sqrt{k}t}}{2i}\right) = Ae^{i\sqrt{k}t}+Be^{-i\sqrt{k}t}
$$$$
\left(\frac{C_1}{2}+\frac{C_2}{2i}\right)e^{i\sqrt{k}t} + \left(\frac{C_1}{2}-\frac{C_2}{2i}\right)e^{-i\sqrt{k}t} = Ae^{i\sqrt{k}t}+Be^{-i\sqrt{k}t}
$$
Its sufficient for the following two equations to hold
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(C_1-iC_2\right) = A
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(C_1+iC_2\right)=B
$$
The solution to those two equations is
$$
C_1 = A+B
$$
$$
C_2 = i(A-B)
$$
So we've shown that we can solve the characteristic equation, get a solution in terms of two complex exponentials, and with clever choice of the arbitrary constants, convert the sum of the two complex exponentials into a sum of sinusoids.